# Connecting postgres database locally with prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database locally with prisma, although I have been receiving an error message.

Here is my prisma.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host:host.docker.internal
            database:esrtech-dev-server
            port:5432
            user:postgres
            password: p@ssw0rd
            migrations: true
```

I am receiving the following error when I attempt to start my environment:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: while scanning a simple key
prisma_1  |  in 'string', line 7, column 5:
prisma_1  |         host:host.docker.internal
```

I have also tried with localhost inside host , but still got and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this issue is associated with the use of a special character in YAML.

Based on the information you have provided, it may be beneficial to start with the password field in the database config.

Your issue may be resolved by adding quotes to our password.

```
password: "p@ssw0rd"
```

Another user had a similar issue that may provide further insights, it is available on the Prisma Github repository (https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2263)

Failing that, you may need to provide a little more information on your environment. As generally the prisma provided docker compose file uses a postgres database in a separate container (managed through the same prisma.yml).